# Is ssh's 'ChrootDirectory' feature considered secure?

Tags: ssh, security, sftp, chroot

I know that a chroot is generally not considered secure and was not designed as a security feature. So my questions are:

1. Am I correct, that chrooting an ssh user (with `ChrootDirectory`) is unsafe and won't prevent that user from escaping? If yes, why would you chroot a user then?
2. Is chrooting a user AND restricting him to SFTP (with `ForceCommand internal-sftp`) more secure? Is there a way to break out of this?

Answer (score 0):

What is "secure"? It is not a boolean value, secure and insecure. In *nix systems, there are various levels of security and privacy.

Talking about `chroot`, it can be always used in a way that is insecure, but SSH is trying to avoid the insecure use cases the most. In the first place, it will not allow to use `chroot` on directory, that is writable by anyone else but `root`. Using `internal-sftp` significantly limits what the user can do inside so unless there is very serious security vulnerability, you should be fine with that.

Comment: With 'secure', I mean that if someone would be able to break out of an ssh-chroot as a non-root user, that this would be considered a bug and would be fixed. Breaking out as root, for example, is possible by design and not considered a bug, which is why it is not secure in that case.